# Office AddIn PowerPoint: OSF.DDA.SlideRange

Tags: typescript, powerpoint, office-addins

Writing an Office AddIn for PowerPoint, I want to call method [`Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=excel-js-preview#getSelectedDataAsync_coercionType__callback_) using TypeScript and using *types*. So basically:

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.SlideRange, (asyncResult) => {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        const slideRange = asyncResult.value as OSF.DDA.SlideRange;
        Logger.Log(slideRange.slides);
    }
    else {
        Logger.Log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
    }
});
```

The problem is that I cannot find the definition for `OSF.DDA.SlideRange`.

**Background:**

According to the docs, the return value received by the callback method is of type [Office.AsyncResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.asyncresult?view=powerpoint-js-preview). In the sample above `asyncResult`. Works: Check!

The type of propertry `value` thereof depends on the `coercionType` parameter. I want to get the slide range. Understood: Check!

Problem: What is the type of `asyncResult.value` for coercion type `SlideRange`? I cannot find any details about it in the documentation. The debug console shows that the type of `asyncResult.value` is `OSF.DDA.SlideRange`:

[image]

So I think, the problem boils down to: **Where is `OSF.DDA.SlideRange` defined?**
I know, I can define an appropriate interface myself, e.g.:

```
interface ISlide {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    index: number;
}

interface ISlideRange {
    slides: ISlide[];
}
```

But surely it must be defined already somewhere!?

Comment: Try typeof  typeof asyncResult.value;

Comment: ``typeof(asyncResult.value)`` returns: `object`